# Find duplicates within a specific period

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with the following structure

```
ID  Person  LOG_TIME
-----------------------------------
1   1       2012-05-21 13:03:11.550
2   1       2012-05-22 13:09:37.050 <--- this is duplicate
3   1       2012-05-28 13:09:37.183
4   2       2012-05-20 15:09:37.230
5   2       2012-05-22 13:03:11.990 <--- this is duplicate
6   2       2012-05-24 04:04:13.222 <--- this is duplicate
7   2       2012-05-29 11:09:37.240
```

I have some application job that fills this table with data.

There is a business rule that each person should have only 1 record in every 7 days.

From the above example, records # 2,5 and 6 are considered duplicates while 1,3,4 and 7 are OK.

I want to have a SQL query that checks if there are records for the same person in less than 7 days.

Comment: So the 7 day `interval` is started with first record date a user have in the table?

Comment: He can at max have 1 record every 7 days. For example if you have one today, you should only get a new record after 7 days or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT ID, Person, LOG_TIME,
         DATEDIFF(d, MIN(LOG_TIME) OVER (PARTITION BY Person), LOG_TIME) AS diff_date
  FROM dbo.Log_time
  )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE diff_date BETWEEN 1 AND 6
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/792cd/1/0)

Answer (score 2):

Please see my attempt on SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b3656/4/0).

You can use a join based on `DATEDIFF()` to find records which are logged less than 7 days apart:

```
WITH TooClose
AS
(
    SELECT
        a.ID AS BeforeID,
        b.ID AS AfterID
    FROM
        Log a
        INNER JOIN Log b ON a.Person = b.Person
                        AND a.LOG_TIME < b.LOG_TIME
                        AND DATEDIFF(DAY, a.LOG_TIME, b.LOG_TIME) < 7
)
```

However, this will include records which you don't consider "duplicates" (for instance, ID 3, because it is too close to ID 2). From what you've said, I'm inferring that a record isn't a "duplicate" if the record it is too close to is itself a "duplicate".

So to apply this rule and get the final list of duplicates:

```
SELECT
    AfterID AS ID
FROM
    TooClose
WHERE
    BeforeID NOT IN (SELECT AfterID FROM TooClose)
```

Comment: good job here :) I will mark you +1, waiting for OP's respond. I reckon I posted only half of my post, but glad you gotten the same with less lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this sample.

Reference: [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c483/1)

Query:

```
select person, 
datediff(max(log_time),min(log_time)) as diff,
count(log_time)
 from pers 
 group by person
;

select y.person, y.ct
from (
select person, 
datediff(max(log_time),min(log_time)) as diff,
count(log_time) as ct
 from pers 
 group by person) as y
where y.ct > 1
and y.diff <= 7
;


PERSON  DIFF    COUNT(LOG_TIME)
1   1   3
2   8   3


PERSON  CT
1   3
```

Comment: Bader sorry I just realized the reference I gave it wrong and it only has the first few breakdowns of the query building. So why not you accept @Tim S's answer? That's the same logic I was sending it to your on my answer anyway. Only difference perhaps mine was in MYSQL and his one is in SQL Server which is what you need. I could update my answer with a function or another alternative method if you need though. Let us know if Tim's answer works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

declare @Count int

```
set @count=(
select COUNT(*) 
from timeslot  
where (( (TimeFrom<@Timefrom and TimeTo >@Timefrom) 
      or (TimeFrom<@Timeto and TimeTo >@Timeto))
      or (TimeFrom=@Timefrom or TimeTo=@Timeto)))
```